# Caption and figure reference to .docx (org-export)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, odt

Captions and figure references by label are lost when converting .odt to .docx with Open Office.
Captions get hidden under the image and truncated by a box.
Numeric references are replaced by “Illustration”.

Is there a way to export to .docx from org-mode and preserve these feature?

MWE:

```
#+ATTR_ODT: :width 10
#+CAPTION: Caption text get hidden by image
#+LABEL: fig:label_image
[[file:./Carl_Spitzweg.jpg]]



See in figure [[fig:label_image]].
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. The best way to achieve this is to export first to latex, and then use pandoc to convert the latex to Word. 
There is, luckily, a library that does this already: `[ox-word][1]`. You'll have to manually install it, since it's not in MELPA. It's part of an Emacs distribution called [scimax](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax).

Once you've downloaded it:

```
(use-package ox-word
:load-path "path/to/dir"
:after ox)
```

And then `C-c C-e w p` to export to Word. Figures and references will work just fine.

`use-package` is a macro that can be installed with MELPA: https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package.

Comment: Is it possible to use this feature in a simple way, without using the full scimax distribution? From my “own” emacs I got `mapcar: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-ref-find-bibliography`. From within scimax, I got lost and export seemed to also fail.

Comment: The instructions I wrote tell you how to use it without the scimax distribution. Just copy the `ox-word` file from the scimax distribution and put it somewhere in your path, then use to code above to load it. The thing is that ox-word depends on `org-ref`, another tool you should definitely get familiar with. Install that first. (The dependency should be listed on ox-word, but it's not. Good catch)

Comment: I now stumble upon `pandoc: nil: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
if: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

(`pandoc -v` yields pandoc 1.19.2.1)

Comment: maybe update to pandoc 2. It's been out for years

Comment: It still fail with pandoc 2.5. Something else must be missing on my box.

Answer (score 0):

> Captions and figure references by label are lost when converting .odt to .docx with Open Office. Captions get hidden under the image and truncated by a box
>
> #+ATTR_ODT: :width 10
> #+CAPTION: Caption text get hidden by image
> #+LABEL: fig:label_image [[file:./Carl_Spitzweg.jpg]]
>
> See in figure [[fig:label_image]].

I don't have access to `Microsoft Office`.  And I am unable to confirm or reject what the original poster says.

***I  can confirm that *I did experience problems* when I imported the ODT file created by `org-9.5.3` in to `Google Docs`.  The image doesn't appear and there appears some stray text in figure number.***  See screenshot below for details.

***What worked for me was to use the [The enhanced ODT exporter](https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt) together with the `#+ODT_APP: docx` keyword.***  You can install the enhanced ODT exporter using instructions at [Getting Started with ODT export (OpenDocument Text Exporter for Emacs’ Org Mode)](https://kjambunathan.gitlab.io/org-mode-ox-odt/Getting-Started-with-ODT-export.html#Installation).

***It looks like the `#+ODT_APP: docx` is a way to generate a `Microsoft Word`-compatible or `Google Docs`-compatible ODT output.***

Down below, first I show the *working* `org` snippet and how it renders when imported in to Google Docs, and next I show the `org` snippets that *do not render well* when imported in to `Google Docs`.

#### With Enhanced ODT exporter `ox-odt-9.5.3.436` and with `#+ODT_APP: docx`

```
#+title: With Enhanced ODT exporter and ODT_APP keyword

#+ODT_APP: docx

This file is exported with /enhanced ~ox-odt~/:
https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt

and with

#+begin_src org
,#+ODT_APP: docx
#+end_src

#+ATTR_ODT: :width 10
#+CAPTION: Caption text get hidden by image
#+LABEL: fig:label_image
[[file:./org-mode-unicorn.png]]

See in figure [[fig:label_image]].
```

[image: With ox-odt-9.5.3.436 and with #+ODT_APP: docx]

#### With Enhanced ODT exporter `ox-odt-9.5.3.436`

```
#+title: With Enhanced ODT exporter

This file is exported with /enhanced ~ox-odt~/:
https://github.com/kjambunathan/org-mode-ox-odt

#+ATTR_ODT: :width 10
#+CAPTION: Caption text get hidden by image
#+LABEL: fig:label_image
[[file:./org-mode-unicorn.png]]

See in figure [[fig:label_image]].
```

[image: With ox-odt-9.5.3.436]

#### On Vanilla Emacs Org-9.5.3

```
#+title: on-vanilla-emacs

This file is exported with ~ox-odt~ that comes with ~org-9.5.3~.

#+ATTR_ODT: :width 10
#+CAPTION: Caption text get hidden by image
#+LABEL: fig:label_image
[[file:./org-mode-unicorn.png]]

See in figure [[fig:label_image]].
```

[image: Captioned Image on Plain Vanilla Emacs Org-9.5.3]